# ui:input* label property issue with late binding

Tags: lightning, ui

Why don't `<ui:inputText>`, `<ui:inputNumber>`, and other tags' `label` attributes get updated for late bound attributes? (forgive me, not sure if late binding is the correct term).

Supposed I have a component like below:

**Component:**

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:attribute name="fieldLabels" type="Map"/>

    <form class="slds-form"> 
        <ui:inputText label="{!v.fieldLabels.field1}" />
        <ui:inputText label="{!v.fieldLabels.field2}" />
    </form>    

    <br />
    <div><b>Values (to see when value changes)</b></div>
    <div>fieldLabels.field1: {!v.fieldLabels.field1}</div>
    <div>fieldLabels.field2: {!v.fieldLabels.field2}</div>
    <br />
    <ui:Button label="Click me" press="{!c.buttonClicked}"/>
</aura:component>
```

**JS Controller:**

```
({
    buttonClicked : function(component, event, helper) {
        var fieldMap = {};
        fieldMap.field1 = 'Fullname';
        fieldMap.field2 = 'Email Address';
        component.set('v.fieldLabels', fieldMap);
    }
})
```

If you click on the <kbd>Click me</kbd> button, you will see that new values are reflected in the lower part. But input labels were not updated.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out with by Setting a default Label value as Empty and its correctly rendering. Try like this.

**In component:**

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:attribute name="fieldLabels" type="Map"/>

    <form class="slds-form"> 
        <ui:inputNumber label="{!(v.fieldLabels.field1 ? v.fieldLabels.field1 : ' ')}" value="{!v.fieldLabels.field1}"/>
        <ui:inputText label="{!(v.fieldLabels.field2 ? v.fieldLabels.field2 : ' ')}" value="{!v.fieldLabels.field2}"/>
    </form>
    <br />

    <div><b>Values (to see when value changes)</b></div>
    <div>fieldLabels.field1: {!v.fieldLabels.field1}</div>
    <div>fieldLabels.field2: {!v.fieldLabels.field2}</div>
    <br />
    <ui:Button label="Click me" press="{!c.buttonClicked}"/>
</aura:component>
```

**In controller:**

```
({
    buttonClicked : function(component, event, helper) {
        var fieldMap = {};
        fieldMap.field1 = 1;
        fieldMap.field2 = 'Email Address';
        component.set('v.fieldLabels', fieldMap);

    }
})
```

Comment: thanks! but that's more of a workaround. my use case is i want to get field labels from a custom object, and use it in my lightning input form, so that they will not be hardcoded. so i would do it via map of string like Map<String,String> fieldLabels, and push it to a component attribute.